# Linux CentOs 2.6.18 Setting locale for cronjobs

Tags: centos, redhat, cron, localization

I have the problem, that I am trying to automate some Informix database job via the crontab.
The job runs fine when done via the command line or processed via the at queue, but not via the crontab. The informix error "-23191 Unable to load locale categories" might indicate that the locale is not set.
How do I set the locale for cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

The locale is usually inferred by the `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables, so try setting these in the crontab itself. For example:

```
LANG=C
LC_ALL=C

0 * * * *   nobody  my-script.sh
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work yet.

Answer (score 1):

The infomix locale need to be set in crontab

```
INFORMIXDIR=/home/informix
CLIENT_LOCALE=es_es.8859-1
DB_LOCALE=es_es.8859-1

0 15 * * *   /home/user/my-script.sh
```

The locale es_es.8859-1 is in my case, you need to check what is your locale.